# jquery/ajax json data function not working

Tags: json, jquery

I have the following function it suppose to talk to another server retrieve the json data and display it the problem is the function is not even initiating a query I'm I doing something wronge? the code is uploaded into the apache tomcat server and I used wireshark for traces and there are none on the http port  here is the code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var home_add='http://wcf.net:3300/gateway';
$('#handshake').click(function(){
alert(" sending json data");
 function handshake(){     /*testing the function */ 
                      var data_send = {
                          "supportedConnectionTypes": "long-polling",
                          "channel": "/meta/handshake",
                          "version": "1:0"
                          };
                      $.ajax({                 /* start ajax function to send data */ 
                          url:home_add,
                          type:'POST',
                          datatype:'json',
                          contanttype:'text/json',
                          async: false, 
                          error:function(){ alert("handshake didn't go through")}, /* call disconnect function */
                          data:JSON.stringify(data_send),
                          success:function(data){
                          $("p").append(data+"<br/>");
                           alert("successful handshake")
                           }                    
                          })   

                          }
})})
```

Thank you in advance for the feedback
Lava

Answer (score 0):

u dont call handshake function...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var home_add = 'http://wcf.net:3300/gateway';
$('#handshake').click(function () {
    alert(" sending json data");
    $.ajax({                 /* start ajax function to send data */
        url: home_add,
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        contanttype: 'text/json',
        async: false,
        error: function () { alert("handshake didn't go through") }, /* call disconnect function */
        data: {
            "supportedConnectionTypes": "long-polling",
            "channel": "/meta/handshake",
            "version": "1:0"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("p").append(data + "<br/>");
            alert("successful handshake")
        }
    });

});
```

});

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply I followed your feedback but it is still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Internet Explorer you have add following code in to your jsp page in head section

```
<script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js" />
```

Try this one and check, may be it will work.